# What is the easiest way to handle window close event in WinAPI for the console application?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, process, synchronization

I'm writing a console multi-process application in c++ using WinAPI. So I have the Dispatcher(e.g. "Parent") and the Client(e.g. "Child") processes. Both processes are synchronized: they're using semaphors, events, mutexes and the pipe (all of them are standard WinAPI handles). Application stop when the user type the `"exit"` command. If the user do so, the dispatcher process notifies it's child, and then child releases its resources and makes another before-exit procedures to exit correctly. But there's a thing that bothers me: what will happen if the user press the window "close" button? If so, I should listen to close event and then perform my resource-releasing procedure. What is the easiest way to handle window close event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a [console handler routine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683242%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) that detects CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT (and CTRL_C_EVENT, if desired), and use [SetConsoleCtrlHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22WINCON%2fSETCONSOLECTRLHANDLER%22%29;k%28SETCONSOLECTRLHANDLER%29;k%28DevLang-%22C%2B%2B%22%29;k%28TargetOS-WINDOWS%29&rd=true) to add the handler routine to your process.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't really different from the client process crashing or being terminated through Task Manager. You ought to be resilient to that as well. The ultimate signal you get for that in the parent process is that the client's process handle will be signaled.

Use WaitForMultipleObjects, along with those other handles, to detect this.